# Retrieve data duplication error

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, arraylist

What i am trying to do:

1. Do 2 rounds of validation to retrieve the data from MySQL, first is to check the time of the day, second to check if that timing is taken, if the timing is not taken i take the data from that row and add it into an arraylist.

Problems:

1. My logic for this is that i run the loop `while(rs.next())`, i will do my first round of checking which is to check the timing, after that when the checking passes it goes into another `if`, and when that passes the check it will get that data from that row and add it into arraylist. However when i run the code, i believe the checking is working BUT it stores the same data over and over again into the arraylist. and in particular it is storing the last row's data, for example where id 1,2,3,4,5,6 passes the validation it will just store id6 over and over again.

   ```
   try {   
       PreparedStatement stmt  = so.getPreparedStatementWithKey("SELECT * FROM et_elderly WHERE room = ?");
       stmt.setString(1, roomNum);
       stmt.executeQuery();
       rs = stmt.getResultSet();

       while(rs.next()){
           if(dosageTime.equalsIgnoreCase("morning")){
               if(rs.getInt("morningtaken")==0){
                   // calculate the age
                   java.sql.Date reportDate=rs.getDate("dob");
                   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                   String text = df.format(reportDate);
                   String year=text.substring(0, 4);
                   String month=text.substring(5,7);
                   String day=text.substring(8,10);

                   // setting the information
                   data.setElderBed(rs.getInt("bed"));
                   data.setElderName(rs.getString("name"));
                   data.setElderAge(ElderData.getAge(year,month,day));
                   data.setElderGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                   DosageList.add(data);   
                   numofElder++;
               }
           }

           else if (dosageTime.equalsIgnoreCase("afternoon")){
               if(rs.getInt("afternoontaken")==0){
                   // calculate the age
                   java.sql.Date reportDate=rs.getDate("dob");
                   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                   String text = df.format(reportDate);
                   String year=text.substring(0, 4);
                   String month=text.substring(5,7);
                   String day=text.substring(8,10);

                   // setting the information
                   data.setElderBed(rs.getInt("bed"));
                   data.setElderName(rs.getString("name"));
                   data.setElderAge(ElderData.getAge(year,month,day));
                   data.setElderGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                   DosageList.add(data);   
                   numofElder++;
               }
           }
           else if (dosageTime.equalsIgnoreCase("noon")){
               if(rs.getInt("noontaken")==0){
                   // calculate the age
                   java.sql.Date reportDate=rs.getDate("dob");
                   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                   String text = df.format(reportDate);
                   String year=text.substring(0, 4);
                   String month=text.substring(5,7);
                   String day=text.substring(8,10);

                   // setting the information
                   data.setElderBed(rs.getInt("bed"));
                   data.setElderName(rs.getString("name"));
                   data.setElderAge(ElderData.getAge(year,month,day));
                   data.setElderGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                   DosageList.add(data);   
                   numofElder++;
               }
           }



       }

   } catch (SQLException e1) {

       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you creating a 'new' object each time?

Comment: Shouldn't:  stmt.setString(1, roomNum);  actually be: stmt.setInt(1, roomNum); Unless of course room is indeed a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a single instance of `data` which is simply updated on each iteration of the `ResultSet`...

```
while(rs.next()){
    if(dosageTime.equalsIgnoreCase("morning")){
        if(rs.getInt("morningtaken")==0){
            //...

            // You never create a new "data" object...
            // setting the information
            data.setElderBed(rs.getInt("bed"));
            data.setElderName(rs.getString("name"));
            data.setElderAge(ElderData.getAge(year,month,day));
            data.setElderGender(rs.getString("gender"));
            DosageList.add(data);   
            numofElder++;
        }
    }
```

So, basically, you're only going to end up with a `List` of objects which are all the same object.  You could test using a `Set` of some kind and you'd end up with a single item in your `Set`.

Instead, you might want to consider using a [Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) or [Builder](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) pattern to ensure that on each iteration through the `ResultSet`, you are creating a new instance of `data` filled with the properties from the database